# Achieving the effect of 'volatile' without the added MOV* instructions?

Tags: c++, c, volatile

I have a piece of code that *must* run under all circumstances, as it modifies things outside of its own scope. Let's define that piece of code as:

```
// Extremely simplified C++ as an example.
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cstdint>
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__GNUG__) || defined(__clang__)
#include <x86intrin.h>
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#include <intrin.h>
#endif

uint64_t some_time_function() {
  unsigned int waste;
  return __rdtscp(&waste);
};

void insert_into_map(std::map<uint64_t, float>& data, uint64_t t1, uint64_t t0, float v) {
  data.emplace((t1 - t0), v);
};

void fn(std::map<uint64_t, float>& map_outside_of_this_scope) {
  const float a = 1;
  const float b = 2;
  float v = 0;
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    uint64_t t0 = some_time_function();
    v = (v + b) - a;
    uint64_t t1 = some_time_function();
    insert_into_map(map_outside_of_this_scope, t1, t0, v);
  }
}

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
  std::map<uint64_t, float> my_map;
  fn(my_map);
  std::cout << my_map.begin()->first << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This looks like an optimal target for the optimizer in compilers, and that is what I have observed with my code as well: `map_outside_of_this_scope` ends up empty. Unfortunately the `map_outside_of_this_scope` is critical to operation and must contain data, otherwise the application crashes. The only way to fix this is by marking `v` as `volatile`, however that makes the application significantly slower than an equivalent Assembly based function.

Is there a way to achieve the effect of `volatile`, without the `MOV` instructions of `volatile`?

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve] . `volatile` has no place in C++ code (that is not accessing hardware registers directly) - so your bug is elsewhere and you need to find it.  Most likely you have Undefined Behaviour and the use of `volatile` changes the behaviour so it appears to work (for now).

Comment: `insert_into_map` shouldn't be optimized out unless the compiler can inline it and prove it has no observable effect. But if it _does_ have an observable effect, something weird is happening. Please show something about `insert_into_map`, how `map_outside_of_this_scope` is defined, etc.

Comment: @RichardCritten That comment is oddly phrased. Perhaps you meant that C++ has no place in hardware-related programming? I fully agree. But accessing hardware registers is far from the only time you need to use `volatile`. Accessing DMA buffers, accessing NVM variables, sharing variables with an ISR and so on. On some systems it can also give memory barrier behavior.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Smells like non-compliant behavior. Clang is known to go muppet when optimizing loops. But you can only tell why the code doesn't work by disassembling it to see if the compiler left out necessary parts. Which in turn means the question cannot be answered without a specific target system in mind.

Comment: <offtopic> @Lundin That C++ has no place in hardware-related programming is an opinion.  And maybe an outdated one. https://www.embedded.com/modern-c-in-embedded-systems-part-1-myth-and-reality/

Comment: Can it be that the compiler is really clever here. After first call v always evaluates to 1. (So only a one time call is enough) and that insert_into_map doesn't use the time values?
WIthout more context it is impossible to say why it is optimized away.

Comment: @PKramer No, C++ is less relevant than ever thanks to C++11 and beyond. And it's not an opinion: Kindly tell me how to do memory mapped hardware register type punning in C++? Or how to declare structs or classes with static storage duration without lagging down my startup code? Or how to block the vast majority of the standard libs from doing heap allocation? And most importantly: how to block inane PC programmers dumped in an embedded systems project from using the various dangerous PC-like features of C++ just because they are available...

Comment: @RichardCritten @Useless @harold I've updated the code to include the missing functions, which should compile on GCC, MSVC and Clang. The code now mostly matches what my actual code does, with the exception of `v = (v + b) - a;` being replaced by work that takes several milliseconds to complete.
@Lundin I have tried GCC, MSVC and Clang, all with identical results when Optimization is enabled. The target is x86-64 (minimum AVX). Even trying different versions of the compilers results in the exact same result where the map is empty.

Comment: The code in the question is fine. You don't need to use `volatile`. The optimizer will not just make a map empty because it feels like it. This code always puts at least one value into the map. The compiler is also not so stupid that it will think __rdtscp always returns the same value.

Comment: @user253751 Unfortunately this is not what I'm seeing. Without volatile, all compilers end up optimizing the entire function away. I was able to identify the exact location by printf debugging, and then reverse engineering the binary to see why the printf inside the function never ended up called: The function didn't exist in the binary. Therefore, it seems I either need volatile, or a keyword that does similar things to volatile, but without read/write from/to memory.

Comment: @Lundin the key point I was trying to make is that - if using `volatile` out side some special cases (not mentioned by OP) fixes a problem. Then the program most likely has some form of UB and using `volatile` changes the way code is generated to mask the problem.

Comment: @Xaymar Does this happen in the code that you put in the question, or does it only happen in your own code that has more code?

Comment: @user253751 It happens in various scenarios, mostly when __rdtscp is used to measure things. The code in the question ended up working, surprisingly enough, but it was meant as an example, as the entire project might be a bit too big for the question at 17.4K lines of code. At least from my end, I can guarantee that everything between t0 and t1 is 100% C++17, with observable side effects like writing packets to memory - yet it ends up optimized away. Which is why I wanted to know if I missed something about a similar keyword to volatile.

Comment: @Xaymar It is likely that something in between t0 and t1 exhibits undefined behaviour.

Comment: I did try the code just by itself, with none of the pseudo-measuring code around it, and it compiles fine and works fine. It's when it's placed between t0 and t1 that it suddenly disappears - even though the location should be identical. As a last ditch effort I tried moving the code into a function, but even that ended up disappearing when placed between t0 and t1. If there is no keyword that is similar to volatile, I might just take the 15.4x performance hit it gives the code until I can write better assembly code for it.

Comment: I don't understand how just omitting the function call is a possible optimization. Did you try to compile with various optimization levels? Does it only happen with -O3 ?

I also don't quite understand why using the time difference as a key is a good idea. You're going to throw away a bunch of the the calculations if they take the same time, unless you're using a multimap

Comment: @PeterT -O2 and -O3 is that I tried, and -Og for debugging where the code reappears in the binary.

Comment: What if you put it in a function and mark it no-inline (using whatever thing is appropriate for your compiler)? Or if that doesn't work, put it in a different translation unit (and don't use LTO)

Comment: Theres so much noise here. What you need to do is create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which exhibits the behavoir you are seeing. Until then we can only largely guess. Do note that `volatile` is very likely the wrong thing to do as its only used in very specialised scenarios which yours isn't as far as we can see.

Comment: ^^^ If the code presented does not demonstrate the issue that you see in your full project, then it follows that some characteristic of the code that was changed / left out is important to the unwanted behavior.  `volatile` is relevant to optimization, but if multiple compilers are optimizing out the whole function then it is likely that either you have UB elsewhere or the compilers all see something about your code that makes the omission valid.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, the question was if there is a keyword similar to volatile without adding mov/movss/movsd to the code. Not "find the potential bug in the code which may or may not exist". I'm unsure how this even evolved in this direction, as I was fairly sure the question was clear.

Comment: If that's what you want to focus on, @Xaymar, then the question is not answerable as posed.  The C and C++ languages  speak only to the semantics of volatile access, not to its implementation.  Or I suppose we could just say"no".

Comment: @JohnBollinger I see, then I'll have to stick with volatile until I can find time to rewrite the function in x86-64 assembly. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Xaymar if your compiler supports it you could try to put an inline assembly block and include "v" in the clobber list. That would only cause one single re-read. I guess this would have a similar effect to what MSalterS already suggested: create a separate volatile variable and only assign "v" to it once per loop iteration before insert_into_map. But I really think there's some context missing as to why the code is optimized out, and fixing that is the actual solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inasmuch as you assert in comments that you are most interested in a narrow answer to the question ...

> Is there a way to achieve the effect of `volatile`, without the `MOV` instructions of `volatile`?

... the only thing we can say is that C and C++ do not specify the involvement of `MOV` or any other specific assembly instructions anywhere, for any purpose.  If you observe such instructions in compiled binaries then those reflect implementation decisions by your compiler's developers.  What's more, where you see them, the `MOV`s are most likely important to implementing those semantics.

Additionally, neither C nor C++ specifies any alternative feature that duplicates the rather specific semantics of `volatile` access (why would they?).  You might be able to use inline assembly to achieve custom, *different* effects that serve your purpose, however.

---

With respect to the more general problem that inspired the above question, all we can really say is that the multiple compilers that perform the unwanted optimization are likely justified in doing so, for reasons that are not clear from the code presented.  With that in mind, I recommend that you broaden your problem-solving focus to search for why the compilers think they can perform the optimization when `volatile` is not involved. To that end, construct a MRE -- not for us, but because the exercise of MRE construction is a powerful debugging technique in its own right.

Comment: I do not believe the code itself to be the problem, as it works fine when by itself - the problem only occurs when trying to measure it. The example code was meant as just a visual example, which was sadly taken as the problem itself even though the title and question were clearly stated differently. Thank you for the answer though, I've marked it as the accepted one.

Comment: @Xaymar Undefined behaviour can be like that. It's undefined. In this case the compiler notices some reason why your code isn't actually allowed to be called and decides to delete it. In the other case the compiler doesn't notice it. But it might notice it next week when you upgrade it! So you should find out why it's doing that.

Answer (score 1):

`volatile` is directly relevant to optimizers because reads and writes of `volatile` variables are *observable behavior*. That means the reads and writes cannot be removed.

Similarly, optimizers cannot remove writes of variables that are observable by other means - whether you write the variable to `std::cout`, file or socket. And the burden of proof is on the compiler - the write can only be eliminated if the write is provably dead.

In the example above, for instance, `mymap.begin()->first` is written to `std::cout`. That is observable behavior, so even in absence of `volatile` the behavior must be kept. But the **exact** details do not matter. An optimizer may spot that only the `->first` member is observed in this particular example. Hence, `v` (the `->second` value) is not observed, and can legally be optimized out.

But if you copy `mymap.begin()->second` to a `volatile float sink`, then that write to `sink` is observable behavior, and the compiler must make sure the right value is written. That pretty much means that your `v` calculation inside the loop needs to be preserved, even though `v` itself is not `volatile`.

The compiler could do loop unrolls that affect *how* `v` is read and written, because the individual `v` updates are no longer observable. Only the value that's eventually written to `volatile float sink` counts.